# Gitstack git server - push to apply changes

Tags: php, git, web, server, gitstack

(Sorry for the unclear title). This is the scenario. I have a local server and I installed Gitstack in it. I was able to to push and pull to this local git server. This same server runs the webapp that I am working on. My plan is to push commits to this local git server and that change must also reflect to the webapp. So instead of using filezilla to copy files from my machine to serer, I will just push the changes via git. How to do it? Or is it possible?

I tried to look inside the Gitstack's installation folder. I expected to see the actual project's files inside but only git files are there.